# The Linux program make has an error：No rule to make a target

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, ubuntu, cmake

I downloaded the Linux version of `opencv-3.2.0.zip`,And use the `cmake` command to install successfully.

`cmake -D CMake_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/opencv ..`

`ippicv_linux_20151201.tgz` downloaded from the `opencv-3.2.0/3rdparty/ippicv/downloads/linux-808b791a6eac9ed78d32a7666804320e` installation catalog before decompression.

Test the following problems：

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/hello.dir/hello.cpp.o
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/workspace/SDKs/opencv-3.2.0/build/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.2.0', needed by `hello'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/hello.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(opencvTest)
set(OpenCV_DIR ../opencv-3.2.0/build)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_executable( hello hello.cpp )
target_link_libraries( hello ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

hellp.cpp

```
#include<cv.h>
int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

The folder name is `opencvTest`,There are `hello.cpp` and `CMakeLists.txt` under the folder.The above problems occur after using the `cmake .` and `make` commands.

Comment: I would ask that on a forum or mailing list related to `opencv`

Comment: Two things: I think the command call should be `cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/opencv ..`. And I don't think `OpenCV_DIR` does take relative paths, so it's more something like `set(OpenCV_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../opencv-3.2.0/build")`.